# CSS selector class and element order

Tags: css

In a HTML table with class of 'testtable', is there any difference between selecting a  element in that table with the following two css selectors?

```
.testtable td{}
```

and

```
td.testtable{}
```

Comment: In first case the `<td>` has to be a child of `.testtable`. In second case the `.testtable` has to be the class of selected `<td>`.

Comment: the second variant won't work if class `.testable` is applied to the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.testtable td{}` selects a `td` that has a parent with the class `testtable`, for example:

```
<table class="testtable">
    <td>I'm selected</td>
</table>
```

`td.testtable{}` selects a `td` that has the class `testtable`, for example:

```
<table>
    <td class="testtable">I'm selected</td>
</table>
```