# CSS tag order confusion when applied to <input> tags

Tags: css

The django stock base.css has a declaration as below:

```
.errors input, .errors select, .errors textarea {
border: 1px solid #c11;
}
```

What does this mean in terms of CSS specificity? Does this mean adding the errors class to an input tag will change the border of that tag to the specified values? I tried it out, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected: [image]

Does this mean an input tag with class errors? That is what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915610/css-selector-class-and-element-order) answer seems to point to. In that case, what can I do to ensure the style is in fact applied? Can someone amplify please?

Comment: This means `learn basic CSS selectors before asking`... [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tutorial+css+selectors&t=ffsb&atb=v67-6b_&ia=web)

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this means if the parent of the input, select or textarea has `class="errors"`, the border will be applied.

Example:

```
<div class="errors">
  <input></input>
</div>
```

If you want to add the class to the input directly...

**HTML**

```
<input class="errors"></input>
```

**CSS**

```
input.errors, select.errors, textarea.errors {
  border: 1px solid #c11;
}
```

It works like this:

`.parent-class element`

or

`element.element-class`

[Read up on CSS selectors here for more.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: That works, however, why does the added css attributes get overridden after being applied to the existing element?